# Slotted elements not added to Custom Web Component in iOS

Tags: javascript, css, safari, web-component

I'm developing a custom web component and when I add options inside via  tag, those are **not rendered for iOS browsers.**

```js
const template = document.createElement('template');

template.innerHTML = `

    <style>
        .my-wrapper {
            height: auto;
            background: #eee;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="my-wrapper">
        <slot name="my-slot"></slot>
    </div>

`;

class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super()
        .attachShadow({mode:"open"})
        .appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }

}

window.customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent);
```

```html
<my-component>
  <option slot="my-slot">A</option>
  <option slot="my-slot">B</option>
  <option slot="my-slot">C</option>
  <option slot="my-slot">D</option>
</my-component>
```

Also available in CodePen: https://codepen.io/agarcav/pen/oNEBZRg

This example works in Chrome Desktop. The slotted elements are added to the web component and they expand it.

Screenshot from Chrome Desktop:
[image]

Is there any needed config in Safari browsers I am missing?

I've googled it but I couldn't find this as a documented bug. According to *Can I use* the support is 100%;

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was the  tag is not rendered in Safari if it's not inside `<select>`, `<optgroup>` or `<datalist>`. Although it's rendered in Chrome and other browsers.

Comment: Yes, that is [in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) under **"permitted parents"**, so Apple has got it right, Chromium is incorrect. There are more tags; ``<tr>`` is notorious: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr#technical_summary)